# Space removal after a pattern in SED

Tags: sed, awk, search

I have a file

instrument.xml

```
bash-4.1$ more instrument.xml
<instr instr_id="CPT-2380950-011-001-826" valor_ch="" instr_type="CurrentAccount" instr_name="CPT-2380950-011-001-826" qn_type="1" ccy_code="GBP" cnt_code="CH" date_issue="2002-05-29 00:00:00" int_rate="0.08000000" eusd_scope="0" cmnt="CRD" status="1"/>
<instr instr_id="VAL-0000001-000" isin="0000001-000 " valor_ch="0000001-000" instr_type="Share" instr_name="******ON" qn_type="1" ccy_code="999" cnt_code="XX" int_rate="0.00000000" eusd_scope="0" cmnt="200" status="1"/>
<instr instr_id="CPT-2411550-011-000-826" valor_ch="" instr_type="CurrentAccount" instr_name="CPT-2411550-011-000-826" qn_type="1" ccy_code="GBP" cnt_code="CH" date_issue="2002-08-02 00:00:00" int_rate="0.08000000" eusd_scope="0" cmnt="CRD" status="1"/>
```

Requirement: 
I need to change [date time] eg 2002-05-29 00:00:00 to [dateTtime] eg2002-05-29T00:00:00 anywhere in the file.
--Some lines wont have date in them so i need to search for date pattern and then do my change --and the columns vary in length 
sed 13 was a very amateur attempt looking for the 13th space(please neglect)

My futile attempts:

```
sed "s/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]/&T/" instrument.xml
grep "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]" test.xml | sed 's/ //13' >instrument.xml ( it doesn’t give me all )

sed "s/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]/&T~+/" instrument.xml |  tr "~" "\n" | sed 's/^+./+/g' ( unable to join only lines which have + in them)
```

Comment: Please clean up you question. (0) Look at what your question looks like. Then look at [Markdown Editing Help](http://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and try to make your question readable. (1) Is your file called `test.xml`, `test.txt`, or `instrument.xml`? (2) Do you need to change `2002-05-29 00:00:00` to `2002-05-29T00:00:00` anywhere in the file, or do you need to change space to `T` in any date/time string of the indicated format?

Comment: (3) Can you solve it yourself if the lines in in your file are < 80 characters long? Is the length of the lines part of the problem? If not, then there's no reason to blast us with your 250-character-long lines. (4) Where does the 13 in `s/ //13` come from? (5) Research regular expressions, specifically sub-expressions.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed "s/\($(printf "[0-9][0-9]%s" '' - - '\) \(' : : '')\)/\1T\2/g"
```

Maybe try building out your pattern programmatically. That can sometimes make it a little easier to nail down the very specific types.

The above expands to...

```
sed 's/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]\) \([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\)/\1T\2/g'
```

*(but without the single-quotes)*

Comment: I hope that the pattern is very long to be misfound so as for me it can be substituted `sed 's/\("[0-9-]\{10\}\) \([0-9:]\{8\}"\)/\1T\2/g'`

Comment: @Costas, but yours also gets ---------- ::::::::

Comment: `perl -pe 's/("\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}")/$1T$2/g'`

Comment: @JJao ... what is that for?

Comment: @mikeserv Yes, but I am sure that such patterns there are not in input file.

Comment: @Costas - and are you equally sure about 0000000000 11111111 ? Or any permutation between these and the others? Because it gets all of them. That pattern is not specific?

Comment: @Costas - and besides, how is `sed 's/\("[0-9-]\{10\}\) \([0-9:]\{8\}"\)/\1T\2/g'` supposed to be easier than `"s/\($(printf "[0-9][0-9]%s" '' - - '\) \(' : : '')\)/\1T\2/g"` - both are simple enough to write, but the latter is more specific.